# NInject simplest example doesn't work

Tags: plugins, ninject

I've got three projects:

1. UI
2. PluginManager
3. PluginOne
4. PluginTwo

Inside my Plugin Manager a create a simple plugin interface:

```
public interface IPlugin<T>
{
    void sayMessage(T message);
    T createMessage();
}
```

So, in my other projects I've two IPlugin implementation:

```
In porject PluginOneProject -->
-------------------------------
public class PluginOne : IPlugin<IntMessage>
{

    public void sayMessage(IntMessage message)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
    }

}

where:

public class IntMessage
{
    private int message;

    public IntMessage(int message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.message.ToString();
    }
}

In porject PluginTwoProject -->
-------------------------------
public class PluginTwo : IPlugin<StringMessage>
{

    public void sayMessage(StringMessage message)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
    }

}

where:

public class StringMessage
{
    private String message;

    public StringMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Obviously, I've added the corresponding project references.
So, in my UI porject I've NInject, and I perform this convention mapping:

```
kernel.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(IPlugin<>))
    .BindAllInterfaces()
);
```

The graph is built correctly.
So, I don't know how to get an instance of PluginOne, or PluginTwo from UI project.

I'm trying to use this code, however, I've a problem with generic interfaces...

```
foreach (IPlugin<?> plugin in kernel.GetAll(typeof(IPlugin<>)))
{
    plugin.sayMessage(plugin.createMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you must request a specific interface from Ninject, so you must request either `IPlugin<IntMessage>` or `IPlugin<StringMessage>`.

I would suggest trying to refactor your app so that you can request a more generic interface, such as `IPlugin`, and/or create a message interface like `IMessage` that each message implements. It's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish.